# Converting real world location to screen coordinates

Tags: geolocation, geo

I want to ask this question without thinking about a specific technology. Suppose I pull a map tile from any maps provider using my real world location. How can I mark my location on this map tile? What is the calculation used here to convert longitude and latitude to pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on OpenGL methods to view data on the earth and I think I'd summarize the position process as follows. This is by no mean the only way to do it by hopefully it helps you to think about the problem.

- Treat the earth's core as the origin of a sphere, convert all polar coordinate of (latitude, longitude, radius) into (x,y,z) for every map points. Same thing for a particular mark you are interested in.
- At this point, you would need to pick a view origin. Say this is your location.
- Rotate everything by view origin's negative longitude through z-axis.
- Rotate everything by view origin's negative latitude through y-axis.
- At this point, the cartesian coordinate of all the points should have view location as the origin. Essentially, you are looking downward to the view origin.
- Finally, scale it down and translate so that (x,y) fits in your coordinate system.